# Mail Not Received

Tags: meteor

I try to send the mail using Meteor with Email package but mail not received

In client side i used this code

```
Meteor.call('sendEmail', 'xxx@sss.com', 'aaa@aat.com','Hello from Meteor!', 'This is a test of Email.send.');
```

In server side

```
Meteor.methods ({
    sendEmail(to, from, subject, text) {

        this.unblock();
        Email.send({ to, from, subject, text });

    }
});
```

In smptp.js

```
Meteor.startup(function () {
    process.env.MAIL_URL = 'smtp://XXXXXXX:6-2KklMXNG4prgdgdfgdgdfgo46ryaMCg@smtp.mandrillapp.com:587';
});
```

Comment: I am not sure whether the env variable has already been read in the mailpackage. Did you try declaring it in the application run command

Comment: Ya i already declared it in package.json.But the mail not receiving

Comment: you usually don't declare environment vairables in `package.json` or are you using something like `dotenv`?  So calling `MAIL_URL="smtp://..." meteor` does not produce any result?

Answer (score 0):

You can't set environment variables like that. You need to put it in your settings file, ie

```
{
  "env": {
    "MAIL_URL": "smtp://XXXXXXX:6-2KklMXNG4prgdgdfgdgdfgo46ryaMCg@smtp.mandrillapp.com:587"
  }
}
```

and then when you run meteor

`meteor --settings settings.json`